# Use of protected specifier in a derived class

Tags: c++, private, protected, derived-class

I am unsure of the correct access specifier for the member var `isMouseOverYard`. In the snippet I don't have plans to inherit from `House`. Option 1 is more consistent with the base class (if I were to inherit from either class I can check whether the mouse is over the object/yard). However, option 2 is more accurate of my current intention, if I do not inherit from `House`. Is there a convention in regards to this usage?

```
class Object
{
protected:
    virtual bool isMouseOverObject() const;
};
```

Option 1

```
class House : public Object
{
protected:
   virtual bool isMouseOverObject() const override;
   bool isMouseOverYard() const;
};
```

Option 2

```
class House : public Object
{
protected:
   virtual bool isMouseOverObject() const override;

private:
   bool isMouseOverYard() const;
}
```

Comment: As they are, your classes are completely useless

Comment: @BЈовић Would you rather see the entire implementation, including everything this question is *not* about?

Comment: @JorenHeit No, I'd rather see a SCCEE (http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My general rule of thumb is constraining the visibility to the biggest possible extent. I.e. I would make `isMouseOverObject` private in `House` class.

Answer (score 1):

Both the options are just fine, option 2 is better, since the supporting methods could be private to your class, hidden from others, being privately confined and accessible to the class members

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter.  I'd leave it `protected` because it's more flexible in the future, and it's a const method anyway so doesn't risk damaging anything too much if someone "misuses" it.

Answer (score 0):

The convention, at least by Bjarne Stroustroup if I remember correctly, is to *never* have protected data. This might seem tempting at times, but it's almost always better to only access data-members through get/set functions. These functions can then be made protected, making them available to derived classes but not to the outside world.

Therefore, in your case, I would go for Option 2, and consider to add some simple get/set functions in case you need them.

EDIT: I was misled to thinking this question was about a variable instead of a function due to a typo by the OP.

Comment: @MichalHosala: the original code in the question missed out the `()` so it looked like a data member.

Comment: Whoops... I glanced over this too damn quick. Thought the isMouseOverYard was a variable. I'll delete my answer.
Edit: @JohnZwinck That explains it...